# Can there exist different smooth, proper schemes over the p-adics with the same generic fiber?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, p-adic-numbers

Can there exist smooth, proper $X_1,X_2/\mathbb Z_p$ such that their generic fibers are isomorphic but their reductions mod $p$ are not? Are there examples if we insist that the special fibers are distinct even over $\overline{\mathbb F}_p$?

An obstruction is that the two reductions should have the same etale cohomology (by proper base change) and tame geometric etale fundamental group (by Grothendieck's comparison theorem).

Comment: There are such examples over any DVR, where the fibres are Hirzebruch surfaces; this is an easy exercise. (Consider suitable extensions of line bundles on $\mathbb{P}^1$ over the DVR.)

Comment: Thank you to both of you! I somehow missed the other question.